# Get cookies set for subdomain

Tags: java, cookies, jsoup

so I am using Jsoup and I am trying to get the cookies set for the site subdomain. The `Connection.Response#cookies` only returns the one set for that domain. I would like to grab the cookies so that I can use them to request data from the subdomain.

Example:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://www.tvplayer.com/watch/dave").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(10000).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://live.tvplayer.com/").timeout(10000).cookies(res.cookies()).get();
```

If you request it throws a 403 due to the cookie not being set, this is because the cookies for the response doesn't have the ones from the subdomain live. just the main domain.

Outputting the cookies gives the cookies `AWSELB` and `PHPSESSID` only.